# MALLET topic-inference

Tags: java, bash, mallet

I am trying to infer the topics of a document based on my trained topic model by MALLET. I am using the following command in the mallet dir

`./mallet infer-topics --inferencer topic-model --input indata.mallet --output-doc-topics infered_docs`

but it gets stuck in cast exception:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: cc.mallet.topics.ParallelTopicModel cannot be cast to cc.mallet.topics.TopicInferencer`

how can I solve this?

Comment: May i know why `bash` is tagged in this?

Comment: It seems that `topic-model` is not a valid type for the `--inferencer` parameter.

Comment: @sjsam since I am using mallet.sh which is a bash script and gets  the arguments of its java code in bash format

Comment: @Berger yes, I think too...but the question is in which format should it be?! I am using the `--output-model` of the `./mallet train-topics` command as` --inferencer` for `./mallet infer-topics`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a difference between a model and an inferencer. The `--output-model FILENAME` option in the `train-topics` command produces a file (a model) that contains the training data along with all the inferred parameters. The `--inferencer-filename FILENAME` produces a much smaller file (an inferencer) that only contains the parameters needed to infer topics for new documents.

The `infer-topics` command needs a topic inferencer, not a complete model. You can create an inferencer from the existing model file by running `train-topics` with the `--input-model FILENAME` and `--inferencer-filename FILENAME` options, with `--num-iterations 0`.